how to add localization to the page in flutter_inappwebview if language queryParam not expected?
I'm using flutter_inappwebview to provide the language via headers as expects the website, please don't hesitate help if you have any opinion, I'm trying to provide the expected value but it doesn't work. It's working principle is if the request is sent from chrome then it will get the locale from the browser's content preferred locale, but if the request is sent from mobile phone then it will get the phone's system language
InAppWebView(
              key: webViewKey,
              initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
                url: WebUri(widget.url),
                headers: {
                  'Accept-Language': language,
                  'Content-Language': language,
                },
              ),
              shouldInterceptAjaxRequest: (controller, ajaxRequest) async {
                return ajaxRequest
                  ..headers = AjaxRequestHeaders(
                    {
                      'Accept-Language': language,
                      'Content-Language': language,
                      if (ajaxRequest.headers != null) ...ajaxRequest.headers!.toMap(),
                    },
                  );
              },
              shouldInterceptFetchRequest: (controller, fetchRequest) async {
                fetchRequest.body;
                return fetchRequest..headers = {'Accept-Language': language, 'Content-Language': language, if (fetchRequest.headers != null) ...fetchRequest.headers!};
              },
              shouldInterceptRequest: (controller, request) async {
                final url = request.url.toString();
                if (url.contains(
                  'https://bankUrl/acs/api/3ds/form',
                )) {
                  if (request.url.queryParameters.containsKey('request_id')) {
                    requestId = request.url.queryParameters['request_id']!;
                  }

                  final urlRequest = URLRequest(
                    url: WebUri.uri(request.url),
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                      'Accept-Language': language,
                      'Content-Language': language,
                      if (request.headers != null) ...request.headers!,
                    },
                    body: utf8.encode('request_id=$requestId'),
                  );

                  final response = await post(
                    urlRequest.url!.uriValue,
                    body: urlRequest.body,
                    headers: urlRequest.headers,
                  );

                  return WebResourceResponse(
                    headers: response.headers,
                    contentType: response.headers['Content-Type'],
                    data: response.bodyBytes,
                    statusCode: response.statusCode,
                  );
                } else {
                  final urlRequest = URLRequest(
                    url: WebUri.uri(request.url),
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                      'Accept-Language': language,
                      'Content-Language': language,
                      if (request.headers != null) ...request.headers!,
                    },
                    body: utf8.encode('request_id=$requestId'),
                  );
                  if (request.method == 'GET') {
                    final response = await get(
                      urlRequest.url!.uriValue,
                      headers: urlRequest.headers,
                    );

                    return WebResourceResponse(
                      headers: response.headers,
                      contentType: response.headers['Content-Type'],
                      data: response.bodyBytes,
                      statusCode: response.statusCode,
                    );
                  } else if (request.method == 'POST') {
                    final response = await post(
                      urlRequest.url!.uriValue,
                      // body: urlRequest.body,
                      headers: urlRequest.headers,
                    );

                    return WebResourceResponse(
                      headers: response.headers,
                      contentType: response.headers['Content-Type'],
                      data: response.bodyBytes,
                      statusCode: response.statusCode,
                    );
                  }
                }
              },
              initialSettings: settings,
              onWebViewCreated: (controller) async {
                webViewController = controller;
                // sendHeadersAccordingToLocale(controller, widget.url);
              },
              onLoadStart: (controller, url) async {
                context.loaderOverlay.show();
              },
              onLoadStop: (controller, url) async {
                var uri = Uri.parse(url.toString());

                uri.queryParameters.forEach(
                  (k, v) async {
                    if (v == 'payment_deposited') {
                      widget.onSuccess();
                      return;
                    }
                    if (v == 'payment_declined') {
                      Get.offAll(() => const Dashboard());
                      Get.to(() => Cancelled());
                      return;
                    }
                  },
                );

                context.loaderOverlay.hide();
              },
              onReceivedServerTrustAuthRequest: (controller, challenge) async {
                debugPrint('onReceivedServerTrustAuthRequest: $challenge');
                return ServerTrustAuthResponse(
                  action: ServerTrustAuthResponseAction.PROCEED,
                );
              },
              onPermissionRequest: (controller, request) async {
                return PermissionResponse(
                  resources: request.resources,
                  action: PermissionResponseAction.GRANT,
                );
              },
              shouldOverrideUrlLoading: (controller, navigationAction) async {
                var uri = navigationAction.request.url!;
                if (![
                  "http",
                  "https",
                  "file",
                  "chrome",
                  "data",
                  "javascript",
                  "about",
                ].contains(uri.scheme)) {
                  if (await canLaunchUrlString(widget.url)) {
                    await launchUrlString(
                      widget.url,
                      webViewConfiguration: WebViewConfiguration(
                        headers: {
                          'Accept-Language': language,
                          'Content-Language': language,
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                    return NavigationActionPolicy.CANCEL;
                  }
                }
                final request = navigationAction.request;
                final url = request.url.toString();
                if (url.contains(
                  'https://bankUrl/acs/api/3ds/form',
                )) {
                  if (request.url!.queryParameters.containsKey('request_id')) {
                    requestId = request.url!.queryParameters['request_id']!;
                  }
                  WebUri? uri;
                  if (!request.url!.queryParameters.containsKey('language')) {
                    uri = WebUri(request.url!.replace(queryParameters: {
                      'language': language,
                      ...request.url!.queryParameters,
                    }).toString());
                  }
                  if ((request.headers?['accept-language'] != null || request.url!.queryParameters.containsKey('language'))) {
                    return NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW;
                  }

                  controller.loadUrl(
                    urlRequest: URLRequest(
                      url: uri ?? request.url,
                      method: request.method,
                      headers: {
                        'Accept-Language': language,
                        'Content-Language': language,
                        'Accept': '*/*',
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                        if (request.headers != null) ...request.headers!,
                      },
                      body: request.body,
                    ),
                  );
                  return NavigationActionPolicy.CANCEL;
                } else {
                  return NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW;
                }
                // return NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW;
              },
              onProgressChanged: (controller, progress) {
                debugPrint(progress.toString());
              },
              onReceivedError: (controller, resourceRequest, webResourceError) {
                debugPrint(webResourceError.description);
              },
              onUpdateVisitedHistory: (controller, url, androidIsReload) {},
              onConsoleMessage: (controller, consoleMessage) {
                debugPrint('errorMessage ${consoleMessage.message}');
              },
            ),

